# Row weights do not work

Tags: navigation

I have a drop down menu of a few items( Drupal 7) and I have assigned them some weights in order to show them in a particular order on the page.
When I save the changes , clear the cache and reload the page , the items don't move and stay in the same order .
Can anyone help ??

Comment: Hello and welcome. We can't help you with implementation we can't see. If it is your custom code, post it. If you configured it via module, name that module (even if it's core menu module) and post a screenshot or description of configuration.

Comment: I have a Taxonomy term called Products and in it I have the list of Products

Comment: Please [edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/112202/edit) details into question. Comments are ephemeral, may disappear if someone will decide to make cleanup ;)